# java ssl socket server handshake aborted

Tags: java, android, ssl, serversocket

I have an android app which is listening for socket connections and can read httpheaders (send by a browser(works all good!)). Now I wont to switch to SSL sockets but I can't get it done.

**things I got working:**

- Keystore
- ServerSocketFactory

**things I not got working (and where I need help):**

- Client accept part

**code:**

```
public void run() {

try {           

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

keyStore.load(service.getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore),"password".toCharArray());

    ServerSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory
                .getDefault();
    SSLServerSocket mServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) socketFactory
                .createServerSocket(8080);
    while (!mServerSocket.isClosed()) {
            mServerSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(mServerSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            mServerSocket.setEnabledProtocols(mServerSocket.getSupportedProtocols());



            System.out.println("waiting");
            SSLSocket client = (SSLSocket) mServerSocket.accept(); 




            client.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener(){

                public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println("handshakeCompleted");

                }

            });
            client.startHandshake(); //MultiThreadWebServer.java:136


            client.getOutputStream().flush();



            client.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
11-29 11:15:01.046: W/System.err(29941): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x4fec3da8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
11-29 11:15:01.046: W/System.err(29941): error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher (external/openssl/ssl/s3_srvr.c:1365 0x41b1e7f8:0x00000000)
11-29 11:15:01.046: W/System.err(29941):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:436)
11-29 11:15:01.046: W/System.err(29941):    at at.aichinger.mario.aws.MultiThreadWebServer.run(MultiThreadWebServer.java:136)
```

to connect to the server I use google cheome and access "https://192.168.0.25:8080" if I do so the Exception gets throwen.

**Code in line MultiThreadWebServer.java:136:**

```
client.startHandshake();
```

Comment: "no shared cipher" - this means your browser and application can't agree what cipher to use (http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html)

Comment: You should remove the line that enables all the supported cipher suites. The ones that aren't enabled by default are insecure, which is why they aren't enabled by default. Ditto the protocols.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these two lines do not make any sense. If you want to restrict supported cipher suites and protocols, define them specifically. But you have to be careful about that not all cipher suites are supported by browsers.

```
mServerSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(mServerSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
mServerSocket.setEnabledProtocols(mServerSocket.getSupportedProtocols());
```

The problem in your code is that you are not using your keystore. Try this:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(service.getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore),
                "password".toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        ServerSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket mServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) socketFactory.createServerSocket(8080);
        while (!mServerSocket.isClosed()) {

            System.out.println("waiting");
            SSLSocket client = (SSLSocket) mServerSocket.accept();

            client.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener() {

                public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println("handshakeCompleted");

                }

            });
            client.startHandshake(); // MultiThreadWebServer.java:136

            client.getOutputStream().flush();

            client.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: now I get this notice/error:
`12-02 18:11:37.603: I/System.out(3976): waiting`

and


`12-02 18:11:53.148: W/System.err(3976): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x4fe33818: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error`

Comment: How did you create your keystore? You can create one like this: `keytool -genkeypair -keystore keystore -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath ./bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar`. Of course you need bouncy castle provider.

Comment: I used [http://portecle.sourceforge.net/](portecle) to create the keystore it uses the Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs. Is there a way to check if the keystore is correct created?

Comment: I am not familiar with that tool. But you can download bouncycastle provider from [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar) and see if your problem is keystore specific or not.

Comment: This can be protocol issue: Server may be configured for only TLS or SSL. You can check with the command  `openssl s_client -connect server:port **-ssl3/tls1** `.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using keystore as default type, always define the type of keystore which you will use in your application. Otherwise There may be the chance where keystore mismatch will happen between server and client.